# Apache HttpClient Error: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters

Tags: java, json, apache, http, httpclient

I'm trying to use Apache HttpClient to get a JSON response from a site's API but it's giving me a "IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters."

Java code:

```
private String orderInURL = "https://r-test.ordr.in";

public String deliveryList(String datetime, String zip, String city, String addr) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String listURL = orderInURL+"/dl/" + datetime + "/" + zip + "/" + city + "/" + 
                addr + "?_auth=1," + this.privateKey;
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(URLEncoder.encode(listURL, "UTF-8"));

    //header
    getRequest.setHeader("accept", "application/json");

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
           + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return output;
}


 ....
 System.out.println(orderin.deliveryList("ASAP", "11111", "MyCity", "100 My Address"));
```

The GET URL turns out to be:

```
https://r-test.ordr.in/dl/ASAP/11111/MyCity/100%20My%20Address?_auth=1,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

If you replace the XXXXXXXXX... with the private key. If I just copied this URL and put it in the browser, the correct JSON returns. I don't know why it doesn't return the correct result in Java. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is but there is a much easier way to read JSON from a URL. Try something like this:

```
public static String readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      return jsonText;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
    return "";
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rfc2616 requires HTTP 1.1 servers to reject HTTP requests without a Host header, see [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) section 14.23.
Try adding the following line before calling `httpClient.execute`:

```
getRequest.setHeader("host", "r-test.ordr.in");
```